# ¿ Cual es la diferencia entre return"vista" y return"redirect:vista" en un metodo POST para Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee, spring-mvc

Lo que pasa es que tengo una vista jsp desde la cual lleno un form, envío los datos por medio del método **POST** hacia mi controlador y una vez terminadas las instrucciones regreso a la vista principal de mi sitio. Sin embargo, los métodos contenidos en mi controlador **GET** para la vista principal no iniciaban, devolviendo la misma completamente limpia sin información, esto utilizando `return"vista.jsp";`

Ahora bien usando `return:"redirect:vista.jsp"` mis métodos van sobre ruedas devolviendo la información, logré solucionar mi error pero quiero entender bien su diferencia ya que quede algo confundido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede en tu aplicación es:

Cuando ejecutas `return"vista.jsp"` regresas al navegador el jsp, supongo que cuando dices

> devolviendo la misma completamente limpia sin información

Es que tu tienes un controller que maneja el `request` del usuario y pone información en tu `vista.jsp`, pero este controlador que muestras no tiene esa lógica, por eso sale "vacía"

Cuando haces un redirect:

Se inicia un `request` por parte del navegador hacia tu url, por tanto el controlador asociado puede cargar la información, **ya que en este momento si esta entrando en el juego**

---

Pequeño esquema de ambos casos

[image: Diferencia entre con y sin redirect]

---

- [Wikipedia URL redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection)
- [Documentación oficial](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3)

Comment: Ese esquema me hizo entender todo, ciertamente leí sobre los métodos pero parece que no salia de la idea principal.

Comment: @MaxSandoval Una imagen vale mas que mil palabras ;)

Answer (score 3):

Si utilizas `return "vista";` el servidor realizará un forward a la vista. Si utilizas `return "redirect:vista";` el servidor realizará un redirect a la url asociada con la vista. Con esto en mente, tu pregunta se traduce en qué diferencias hay entre un forward y un redirect. Estos conceptos no están asociados a Spring sino al desarrollo de aplicaciones Web en Java.

### Forward

Tu petición devolverá una respuesta con código 200, 201 u otro, por ejemplo 500 si sucede un error durante la atención del request. En este caso, el contenido de la respuesta será el contenido de tu vista, es decir, tu JSP. Los beneficios son que se pueden reutilizar los atributos puestos en el alcance request para utilizarlos en la renderización de la vista. Esto es, al utilizar Forward puedes hacer esto:

Código en el controller:

```
public String ejecutaPost(Model model) {
    model.add("saludo", "hola mundo!");
    return "vista";
}
```

Código en la vista (usualmente JSP):

```
<p>El servidor manda un saludo: ${saludo}</p>
```

### Redirect

Tu petición devolverá una respuesta con código 300 HTTP indicando que el cliente (el navegador) tiene que realizar una nueva petición a otra url del servidor (o quizás de un servidor externo). El servidor recibirá esta petición y la atenderá.

En este caso, no se pueden aprovechar los atributos puestos a nivel de request porque se va a generar un nuevo ciclo request-response hacia el servidor.

Comment: Creo que gane por la imagen jeje, pero tu respuesta es exacta ;)

Comment: Definitivamente ambos tenían la razón, pero me encontraba bloqueado con la teoría necesitaba algo visual para salir de mi idea principal.

Gracias a ambos.