# Problema al cerrar sesion aplicacion web java utilizando ejb + jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, web, ejb

Estoy utilizando Glassfish server 4.1.1, java EE7 web, jdk 1.8 y jsf 2.2
La pantalla principal de la app es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego doy clic en ingresar, escribo las credenciales, ingreso e inicia sesion como se muestra en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al dar clic en el link de salir me da el siguiente error.

**Este es el error**

> FATAL:   JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException durante el procesamiento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=/templates/menu_todos.xhtml @10,48 test="#{!homeController.logueado()}" /templates/menu_todos.xhtml @10,48 test="#{!homeController.logueado()}": java.lang.NullPointerException
>   FATAL:   /templates/menu_todos.xhtml @10,48 test="#{!homeController.logueado()}" /templates/menu_todos.xhtml @10,48 test="#{!homeController.logueado()}": java.lang.NullPointerException
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /templates/menu_todos.xhtml @10,48 test="#{!homeController.logueado()}" /templates/menu_todos.xhtml @10,48 test="#{!homeController.logueado()}": java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:358)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getBoolean(TagAttributeImpl.java:150)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.IfHandler.apply(IfHandler.java:91)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:194)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:124)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>       at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1006)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>       at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /templates/menu_todos.xhtml @10,48 test="#{!homeController.logueado()}": java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:356)
>       ... 59 more
>   Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:336)
>       at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
>       at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:136)
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:63)
>       at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>       ... 60 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at miApp.controllers.SessionUtil.getUserLog(SessionUtil.java:36)
>       at miApp.controllers.HomeController.logueado(HomeController.java:152)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor154.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
>       ... 68 more

**XHTML**

```
<h3><h:outputText value="Menu Usuario" /></h3>

<c:if test="#{!homeController.logueado()}">        
    <h:form><h:commandLink action="#{homeController.login()}" value="Ingreso" /></h:form>
</c:if> 

<c:if test="#{homeController.logueado()}">
    <h:form><h:commandLink action="#{homeController.cambio_clave()}" value="Cambio Clave" /></h:form>
    <h:form><h:commandLink action="#{homeController.logout()}"  value="Salir"  /></h:form>
</c:if>
```

**Controlador:**

```
package miApp.controllers;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import miApp.dao.UsuarioDAO;
import miApp.models.Usuario;
/**
 *
 * @author jgzamzam
 */
@ManagedBean
@Named(value = "homeController")
@SessionScoped
public class HomeController implements Serializable {
@EJB
private UsuarioDAO dao;

@Size(min=1, message="Debe ingresar un usuario")
private String usuario;

@Size(min=1, message="Debe ingresar un usuario")
private String clave;

@Size(min=1, message="Debe ingresar un usuario")
private String claveAct;

@Size(min=1, message="Debe ingresar un usuario")
private String claveNew;

@Size(min=1, message="Debe ingresar un usuario")
private String claveRep;

//+++Constructor de la Clase
public HomeController() {
}

//++++ Setters and Getters

public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public String getClave() {
    return clave;
}

public void setClave(String clave) {
    this.clave = clave;
}

public String getClaveAct() {
    return claveAct;
}

public void setClaveAct(String claveAct) {
    this.claveAct = claveAct;
}

public String getClaveNew() {
    return claveNew;
}

public void setClaveNew(String claveNew) {
    this.claveNew = claveNew;
}

public String getClaveRep() {
    return claveRep;
}

public void setClaveRep(String claveRep) {
    this.claveRep = claveRep;
}   


//++++Metodos del Bean
public String index(){
    return "/index";
}//++++Fin public String index

public String acercaDe(){
    return "/home/acerca_de";
}
//++++Fin public String acercaDe

public String login(){
    return "/home/login";
}
//++++Fin public String login

//++++Funcion Ingreso al Sistema
public String ingresar(){
    Usuario login = dao.getLogin(usuario, clave);

    //Si el login no es correcto se queda en la pagina actual
    if(login == null){
        SessionUtil.addErrorMessage("Usuario o Clave incorrecto");
        return null;
    }

    //Cierra la sesion y la crea con el nuevo usuario
    SessionUtil.closeSession();
    SessionUtil.addSession(login.getId(), login.getNombre(), login.getTipousuarioId().getId(), login.getTipousuarioId().getNombre());
    return "/index";
}//Fin String ingresar

public String logout(){
    SessionUtil.closeSession();
    return "/index";
}//Fin public String logout

public String cambio_clave(){
    return "/home/cambio_clave";
}//Fin public String cambio_clave

//Funcion para cambiar la clave del usuario
public String cambiarPWD(){
    //si la clave nueva y la repeticion no coinciden, ERROR
    if(!(claveNew.equals(claveRep))){
        SessionUtil.addErrorMessage("Las claves ingresadas no son identicas");
        return null;
    }

    //Recupera el usuario actual para conocer su clave
    Usuario current = dao.find(SessionUtil.getUserLog());
    String claveUsr = current.getClave();

    //La clave del ususario debe ser igual a la actual
    if(!(claveAct.equals(claveUsr))){
        SessionUtil.addErrorMessage("La clave actual no coincide con la de su usuario");
        return null;
    }

    current.setClave(claveNew);
    dao.edit(current);
    return "/index";    
}//Fin public String cambiarPWD

//Funcion que determina si hay un usuario logueado
public Boolean logueado(){
    Integer userLog = SessionUtil.getUserLog();
    return !(userLog == null);        
}
```

**Session Util**

```
package miApp.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * @author jgzamzam
 */
public class SessionUtil {

//Se crean las variables de sesión
public static void addSession(Integer userId, String userNombre, Integer tipo, String userTipo){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession sesion = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    sesion.setAttribute("userLog", userId);
    sesion.setAttribute("userNombre", userNombre);
    sesion.setAttribute("userTipoId", tipo);
    sesion.setAttribute("userTipo", userTipo);
}

//Se cierra la sesión
public static void closeSession(){
    ExternalContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ((HttpSession) ctx.getSession(false)).invalidate();
}

//Recupera el código del usuario logueado
public static Integer getUserLog(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession sesion = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    Integer userLog = (Integer)sesion.getAttribute("userLog");
    return userLog;
}
```

Comment: solo añade el código relevante

Comment: Yo cambiaría que la opción de logout esté en un bean tipo `@RequestScoped` y que se haga redirect en lugar de forward. Es decir, en lugar de `return "/index.xhtml";` haría `return "/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"`

Comment: Muchas gracias Luiggi tú solución me funciono, pero mas que por el cambio del bean a @RequestScoped..... la solución estuvo en cambiarle el return que yo tenia por el que tu me pasaste en la respuesta "return "/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"...... me podrías indicar cual es la diferencia o que es lo que hace tu return en comparación con el que tenia???

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el devolver una cadena en el método usado como action indicará que JSF ejecute un forward a la vista cuyo nombre sea la cadena devuelta. Es decir:

```
public String metodoAction() {
    /* lógica de tu action... */
    return "/pagina.xhtml"; //<-- nombre de la vista a hacer forward
}
```

Puesto que haces forward, tu contenedor de servlets/servidor de aplicaciones intentará reutilizar los elementos del request actual, entre ellos la sesión, pero tu sesión ha quedado invalidada por la ejecución de `Session#invalidate`, lo que hace que la sesión de **el request actual** (el que se usa para generar la vista en el forward) sea `null`. Por ende, el NPE.

Lo que debes hacer es iniciar un nuevo request. Para ello, en lugar de hacer forward lo que debes hacer es redireccionar a una página. El redirect indica que se generará un nuevo ciclo request/response para tu aplicación. Este nuevo request estará asociado a una nueva sesión. Para lograr un redirect desde un action en JSF, debes agregar `?faces-redirect=true` al final de la cadena:

```
public String metodoAction() {
    /* lógica de tu action... */
    // nombre de la vista, con el parámetro JSF lo interpreta
    // para hacer un redirect (retornar código 303) y no un forward
    return "/pagina.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Los conceptos de forward y redirect no son propios de JSF, pertenecen a Java EE. Puedes ver una explicación de las diferencias [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4698/227).

---

Adicional a ello, puedes mejorar la aplicación al dividir ciertas acciones al request donde debería estar. Por ejemplo, un cierre de sesión le corresponde más a un bean de alcance request, puesto que los bean con `@ViewScoped` o `@SessionScoped` se almacenan en la sesión (aquella que estás invalidando y que puede eliminar la sesión y los elementos que hay en ella).

Answer (score 0):

Si el usuario no está logueado,la variable userLog no está en sesión. Estas haciendo casting a Integer de esa variable sin comprobar primero si es distinta de null, y por eso salta la excepción.
Comprueba que

```
sesion.getAttribute("userLog")!=null
```

antes de

```
Integer userLog = (Integer)sesion.getAttribute("userLog");
```

Comment: Gracias por el interes Pablo, edite la pregunta y como veras el usuario si se loguea previamente y luego al querer salir es el problema........disculpa si talvez no estoy entendiendo tu respuesta soy nuevo en el mundo de java!!!!

Comment: El problema parece estar en que no se está guardando correctamente el valor de "userLog" en sesión, o tu DAO devuelve un valor nulo para login.getId(). Revisa esos dos puntos.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente Pablo, lo del "userLog" ya lo comprobe y si me muestra el valor entero al pie de la pag(osea 1 o 2 o 3) segun sea el usuario logueado........ lo del DAO no entiendo a que te refieres, una vez mas disculpa soy nuevo en esto de java

Comment: No es eso, es simplemente que getExternalContext().getSession(false) de vuelve nulo. El problema no es en el casteo. (el false asegura que no se creará nueva sesión sino que traerá la existente si es que hubiera), favor de ver la respuesta que publiqué.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es bastante claro en tu log:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   miApp.controllers.SessionUtil.getUserLog(SessionUtil.java:36) at
>   miApp.controllers.HomeController.logueado(HomeController.java:152)

El origen del `NullPointerException` se da en tu clase `SessionUtil` y es porque intentas obtener un `Session` que ya no existe pues acabas de cerrar la sesión y por ende invalidarla en el contexto. Eso provoca que al hacer:

```
HttpSession sesion = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
sesion.getAttribute("userLog");
```

Estás haciendo:

```
HttpSession sesion = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
// sesion es nulo, aunque se castee a HttpSession
null.getAttribute("userLog");
```

Te sugiero antes de hace eso verificar que sesion es diferente de null:

```
if (sesion == null) {
    // Aquí va tu código
    sesion.getAttribute("userLog");
}else {
 return null;
}
```